# Maven / M2Eclipse excludes my resources all the time

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have two very annoying issues with Maven-Eclipse integration, from time to time it excludes all my resources in src/main/resources and src/test/resources from the build path.

If I inspect "Properties >> Java Build Path >> Source" I can see that these two folders have "Excluded: **".

The problem can be easily solved by clicking on "Remove" on the exclusions, but it is really-really frustrating.

The project setup is very simple, it has some modules and sub-modules, but nothing fancy. I don't have any configuration options in my pom.xmls regarding resources, eclipse or whatever (maybe I should?).

The other problem is that Eclipse keeps reporting warnings in the "target" directories (in the "Problems" view), where it shouldn't give a damn in the first place.

Ps: Springsource Tool Suite 2.7.0.RELEASE, Maven Integration for Eclipse 0.12.1.20110112, Maven 2.2.1

Comment: Did you get it solved?

Comment: Can you edit this question, so it contains one question instead of two?
@AnmolGupta doesn't the accepted solution work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct behavior.  Current version of M2E provide their own contributor to the automatic build process inside the Eclipse IDE.  This build process takes into account the maven lifecycle for generate-resources and process-resources etc...  i.e. some project have plugins that generate resources from configuration and put in the compiled output folder.

The mechanism you are looking at in the Build Path only relates to the Eclipse IDEs built in mechanism to compile/assembly a set of input source folders into the output folders.  If both Maven and Eclipse did this there would be conflicts/problems.

There is a link in the M2E FAQ about this exact point https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-faq.html#how-to-configure-proxy-and-location-of-maven-local-repository

If you are genuinely having problems with resources not being copied maybe we can work through why that is (since that is another matter), but your main question is about a common M2E FAQ point.

Maybe you want to upgrade to org.eclipse.m2e and Indigo as a lot of Maven complex maven issues/usage I have are mostly resolved or have an explained solution.

.

I would recommend you perform a "Run As -> Maven -> clean" and then a "Project -> Clean" then enable automatic bulding (this is to allow Eclipse based automatic build to take place, do not use Run As -> Maven to build to test this point).  Now open a file manager outside eclipse and manually inspect the output folders for the resources that you did not think are being copied.  You should find they are there just the same.

.

I agreed with the (probably Validation) warning about items in the target/** directory and whilst Eclipse has a way to manually exclude the target/** directory from validation this option does not stick beyond a project clean (when the target directory is deleted).

So it is somewhat annoying to be always waiting for validation of items in a large project.

Maybe I attempt to see if a Maven Eclipse connector plugin can be created provided to do this i.e. tie into the build lifecycle and automatically apply the Exclude Validation on the target folder.

Comment: exclusion **, is correct and as it should be, you obviously did not understand the explanation why it is correct, please research and read up again.

Comment: sadly this means running JUnit tests that rely on context files becomes complicated, because Eclipse does not see resources/** :(

Comment: This is also a bit of a pain when you are working with GWT's UiBinder functionality. Maven does not allow XML files in the source code, but then doesn't let the GWT plugin see them during the development process. I remove the *.* filter and I'm fine until I need to update a dependency. There should be an option.

Comment: after maven clean and project clean, project automatic build, error "xxx is missing required source folder:target/generated-sources", target/generated-test-sources

Comment: well, the answere is not completely correct, as the M2Eclipse FAQ is not conmpleteley correct.

In Particulat this part is not correct: "Also note, that classpath used for JUnit and Java Application launch configurations for projects that have Maven support enabled is also calculated in a special way and *** excluded resources does not affect it either ***." Actually it affects the launch configuration of the UNIT/Integration tests, as the resources are neither copied to the target, nor included in the classpath.

Comment: So ... for the time being, the only solution I have is to manually remove exclusions for each project after each "project update". And that is annoying and time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

T_T not a good solution. resources is not copied without maven-update

---

maven resources:resources phase marked ignored in Lifecycle Mappings will cause this problem.

As Miles pointed out above, eclipse don't copy the resource since it assumes maven will do it for you. Then if resources:resources phase which do the job in maven is not executed, you get a file not found exception at runtime.

to check this open

project->properties->maven->lifecycle mapping

and see whether resources:resources is marked ignored or not.

to solve it windows->preference->maven->lifecycle mapping-> open workspace lifecycle mappings metadata

then change

```
  <action>
    <ignore />
  </action>
```

to

```
  <action>
    <execute />
  </action>
```

for goal `resources`

reload metadata & update maven project

should solve the problem.

Comment: FWIW did you ensure to install m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin ?  Do you still require the above answer ?  As I understand it this makes a lot of goal/plugins that affect classpath/building just work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

step 1. delete the project from eclipse
step 2. import the project freshly
step 3. Go to the folder required to be added as source folder.

Please refer below screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Your image is no longer accessible.